# How can I search for photos by height or width?

Tags: command-line, nautilus

I would like to search for photos that have a 4:3 aspect ratio and then copy them to a flash drive for use in a digital frame. I know how to do this in Windows with `height:3000` (for example) in the graphical shell. How can I do the same either in Nautilus or with the command line?

Comment: what about this command "identify *.jpg | grep 3000"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use simple shell script for this. 
create any file `search.sh` in your photos folder using

```
gedit search.sh
```

and paste bellow lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir  /home/$USER/test
for i in *.jpg; do
read -r w h <<<$(identify -format "%w %h" "$i")
if [ `expr $h / $w` ==  `expr 4 / 3` ]; then
cp "$i" /home/$USER/test/
fi
done
```

save this file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and make it executable using

```
sudo chmod +x search.sh
```

then execute it using command

```
./search.sh
```

it will copy all photos that have `4:3` to `test` directory in your home directory. 
if you want copy to flash drive or somewhere else then make change in script and if `identify` command is not available in your system then you can install is using command:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: And why `sudo gedit search.sh`

Comment: You get immediately a problem, if the file names contain spaces. Please check your code here http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: After that, I will remove my DV. ;)

Comment: @A.B. thanks i made that change. now it working with space also

Comment: @pl_rock, you're smarter than me...a shell script solves most of the world's ills.

Answer (score 1):

#### Extracting images from a recursive directory

The script below will copy images of a 4:3 ratio, from a source directory recursively into a target directory. The script reads all common image formats, non- image files are ignored (raising in `IOError`)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import shutil
from PIL import Image
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]; target = sys.argv[2]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    for f in files:
        try:
            file = root+"/"+f
            img = Image.open(file); size = img.size; ratio = size[0]/size[1]
            if ratio == 4/3:
                shutil.copyfile(file, target+"/"+f)
        except (IOError, ValueError):
            pass
```

#### How to use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `search_ratio.py`
- Run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/search_ratio.py /source/directory /target/directory
  ```

If one or more directories include spaces, use quotes. 
An example command I used for testing:

```
python3 '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/pscript_4.py' '/home/jacob/Bureaublad' '/home/jacob/Afbeeldingen/test'
```

#### In case you are extracting images from a "flat" (single) directory

Then the script can be a little simpler:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import shutil
from PIL import Image
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]; target = sys.argv[2]

for f in os.listdir(dr):
    try:
        file = dr+"/"+f
        img = Image.open(file); size = img.size; ratio = size[0]/size[1]
        if ratio == 4/3:
            shutil.copyfile(file, target+"/"+f)
    except (IOError, ValueError):
        pass
```

Use it exactly like the first one.

Note that with the first script, you will get name clashes in case of duplicated names in different source folders.