# Tools to help filter out files (mostly images)

Tags: data-recovery, filemanager

I was recently on a trip and on my way back I lost lot of my pictures to a computer crash. After using photorec I am left with a dump of over 4000 pictures from which I need would want to keep only 1000-1500. Are there any software apps or tools that can help me sort out files in a specific folder?

If I can sort out the pictures according to their:
-Date of capture
-size range (between 1 to 4 MB)
-Pixel dimension (greater than or less than a certain size)
-Maybe color range, something like google's color filter. (i know it is a long shot that anything like it exists yet but if there is, would love to know)

it will help me avoid a lot of trouble.

Thanks.

I have both windows as well as linux available on my system so if you know how to get this done on either of the two OS I would be really glad.

Comment: Size: you could use an edited version of one of the answers here; combine it with the command to move certain files, above a certain size tec. just mention if you need it edited.

Comment: Other options: Width: http://askubuntu.com/questions/690421/how-can-i-search-for-photos-by-height-or-width/690669#690669,  Date: http://askubuntu.com/questions/582799/reorganize-photos-from-an-existing-folder-structure-into-a-new-structure/583355#583355 Probably more available around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you Linux command-line-literate? Then `find` is your friend.

You did not tell us what format the "pictures" are, nor what sort of file system they're stored in.

Read (and re-read) `man find`.

`find` will let you traverse the recovered files, and Do Things to them either individually or as a group.

Knowing the data format of each "Picture" (read `man file`, and do `man -k` on the result) could let you extract the Picture's creation time/date.

I don't know of a solution for the Linux-command-line-illiterate, sorry.